# LDAP sort control with subfield precision?

Tags: sorting, ldap

I have a bunch of people in an LDAP with cn values like "smith1", "smith2", "smith99", etc.

Is there a way to specify a server-side sort control that would return the usernames in numerical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side sorting control can be used to sort entries based on SN according to the DirectoryString ordering rules which is alphabetic order. There is no way to define a sort that will be partially based on alphabetic order and then partially on numeric order (when the names ends with digits).

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that for any given search result, the alphabetic portion of the CNs will be identical (i.e. they will be all _smith_ or _jones_); only the numeric portion will differ.  Would a pure numeric sort work in that case?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I don't think so... Most servers will detect a syntax error, when trying to do integerOrderingMatch and the value doesn't start with digits.